# How can I check whether a Double value overflows?

Tags: scala, floating-point

I want to check if adding some value to a double value exceed the Double limits or not. I tried this:

```
 object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var t = Double.MaxValue
    var t2 = t+100000000
    if(t2 > 0) {
      println("t2 > 0: " + t2)
    } else
      println("t2 <= 0: " + t2)
  }

}
```

The output I get is

```
t2 > 0: 1.7976931348623157E308
```

What I actually want is to sum billions of values and check whether or not the running sum overflows at any time.

Comment: Can you subtract **first-value** from Double.MaxValue and check if that is greater than **second-value**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of your question seems to stem from a misunderstanding of floating-point numbers.

1. IEEE-754 floating-point numbers do not wrap around like some finite-size integers would. Instead, they "saturate" at `Double.PositiveInfinity`, which represents mathematical (positive) infinity. `Double.MaxValue` is the largest finite positive value of doubles. The next `Double` after that is `Double.PositiveInfinity`. Adding any double (other than `Double.NegativeInfinity` or `NaN`s) to `Double.PositiveInfinity` yields `Double.PositiveInfinity`.

   ```
   scala> Double.PositiveInfinity + 1
   res0: Double = Infinity

   scala> Double.PositiveInfinity - 1
   res1: Double = Infinity

   scala> Double.PositiveInfinity + Double.NaN
   res2: Double = NaN

   scala> Double.PositiveInfinity + Double.NegativeInfinity
   res3: Double = NaN
   ```
2. Floating-point numbers get fewer and farther between as their magnitude grows. `Double.MaxValue + 100000000` evaluates to `Double.MaxValue` as a result of roundoff error: `Double.MaxValue` is so much larger than `100000000` that the former "swallows up" the latter if you try to add them. You would need to add a `Double` of the order of `math.pow(2, -52) * Double.MaxValue` to `Double.MaxValue` in order to get `Double.PositiveInfinity`:

   ```
   scala> math.pow(2,-52) * Double.MaxValue + Double.MaxValue
   res4: Double = Infinity
   ```

---

Now, you write

> What I actually want is to sum billions of values and check whether or not the running sum overflows at any time.

One possible approach is to define a function that adds the numbers recursively but stops if the running sum is an infinity or a `NaN`, and wraps the result in an `Either[String, Double]`:

```
import scala.collection.immutable

def sumToEither(xs: immutable.Seq[Double]): Either[String, Double] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def go(ys: immutable.Seq[Double], acc: Double): Double =
    if (ys.isEmpty || acc.isInfinite || acc.isNaN) acc
    else go(ys.tail, ys.head + acc)
  go(xs, 0.0) match {
    case x if x.isInfinite => Left("overflow")
    case x if x.isNaN => Left("NaN")
    case x => Right(x)
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I want to get the total of billions of values and check if the total overflows anytime or not. Could you please tell a way to check that?

Answer (score 2):

In response to your question in the comments:

> Actually, I want to get the total of billions of values and check if the total overflows anytime or not. Could you please tell a way to check that?

If the total overflows, the result will be either an infinity (either positive or negative), or NaN (if at some point you have added a positive and negative infinity): the easiest way is to check `total.isInfinity || total.isNaN`.

Comment: I was updating my answer, when you posted yours :)